# Python pyserial module installed but giving error No module name serial

Tags: python

I have a python code running in Ubuntu. I have installed pyserial module but giving me same error that No Module named serial.
Thanks in advance

```
from serial import *
import time
import MySQLdb
dbhost = 'localhost'
dbname = 'Temperature'
dbuser = 'root'
dbpass = 'nagios12345'
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600,) # On Ubuntu systems,     /dev/ttyACM0 is the default path to the serial device on Arduinos, yours is likely different.
flag = 1
the_goods=''
while (flag) :

time.sleep(10)

the_goods = ser.readline()

str_parts = the_goods.split(' ')

conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = dbhost,
user = dbuser,
passwd = dbpass,
db = dbname)
cursor = conn.cursor ()
sql = "INSERT INTO Temperature (Temp) VALUES ('%s');" % (str_parts[0])
try:
cursor.execute(sql)
except:
    pass
    cursor.close ()
    conn.commit()
    conn.close ()
print(the_goods)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the line `from serial import *` to `import serial`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line:

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600,)
```

to

```
ser = Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600,)
```

Since you are using `from serial import *`, you don't need to put `serial.Serial`.

Comment: Same Error i am receiving RatDon

Comment: @SheikhAlBilal Can you post the exact Error message. And at the end before the bracket, `,` is required!!

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "serial_reader_mysql.py", line 1, in <module>
    from serial import *
ImportError: No module named 'serial' @RatDon

Comment: Can you mention the python version you are using and how did you install pyserial?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using python 2.7 or 3.4?

I found that python2.7 knows what the `serial` module is, but python3.4 doesn't.

I have no idea why, and I'd really like a way to get it working on 3.4, but at least using 2.7 is a workaround.